# Python Discord Bot Offline

Tags: python, heroku

I am creating a Discord bot. I use Heroku to run it for 24/7. When I deploy it, it does not go online.

I used `discord` library (`discord.py`).

My codes are in my GitHub repository. Here: https://github.com/rohattunaciftci/sectorvpython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to edit the requirements.txt

from discord.py=='0.16.12' to discord.py==0.16.12

for instance,
cx_Freeze=='5.1.1' this line won't work, but 
cx_Freeze==5.1.1 on the other hand will.

I guess it reads the file as a string and the pip converts the value after the '==' to numbers or just save as it.
when you add '' it won't match the results

" '5' " != "5"

Comment: I will ask one more question. How can i stop my app on Heroku for a while?

Comment: go to settings and then turn the Maintenance Mode off.
supposed to be almost at the end of the page

Comment: In Python my bot does not go online. In Node JS it does. Why?

Comment: debug it, google the debug results.
If you didn't succeed searching, post *new* question.
and more people that have the same problems will learn from it.
and I think you should change the title of the Post since its requirements install issue :)

Comment: How can i debug? And how can i get printed texts etc. while running my python script? I am new in Heroku